# Logging queries missing index in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing

I am trying to see which queries I have that don't use indexes.

In the shell, I did:

```
> set global log_queries_not_using_indexes=1;
```

This turned on the option, as confirmed by `show global variables`. How do I set which file the query_log is being printed to? I tried setting a couple of them, but none of them seemed to be the one it was writing to. What do I need to do to see this query log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will be logged to the slow query log.

Set the location of the slow query log like this:

```
slow_query_log_file=file_name
```

More info:

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html
```